# LINQ Join on multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

What would be the equivalent of the following T-SQL query in L2E using Lambda expressions?

```
Select * from a INNER JOIN b on a.Foo = b.Foo OR a.Foo = b.Bar
```

I want to join a and b when `a.Foo` equal to `b.Foo` OR `b.Bar`

Thanks.

Comment: It's [usually a mistake to use `Join` in LINQ to Entities](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/). But since you're asking about a made-up "Foo" and "Bar" instead of describing your real problem, it's hard to help with that.

Comment: @CraigStuntz: I used Foo and Bar because they're of no value in my question. FYI, `(a.ID = b.a_ID OR a.ID = b.ID)` this is the real Foo and Bar.

Comment: So what are the navigations related to those IDs? Do you have any?

Comment: b.a_id is a foreign key to a.id.  Also, b.id is b's primary key **and** a foreign key to a.id

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Do you have navigation properties on whatever the heck `a` is corresponding to the entity `b`? If so, you should be using those, not reinventing entity relationships. Read the blog post in my first comment.

Comment: @CraigStuntz: Seems like you're not in the mood today! I know about navigation properties and I just mentioned about the foreign key associations between a and b. each association has its own navigation property. Nevertheless, Jon Skeet answered my question clearly. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do an "or" style join in LINQ with an actual join clause. All join clauses in LINQ are equijoins. The closest you can come is a where clause:

```
var query = from a in A
            from b in B
            where a.Foo == b.Foo || a.Foo == b.Bar
            select new { a, b };
```

Comment: What do you mean *equijoin*? Equijoin is a join statement that uses only equality comparisons but the **join predicate can contain multiple conditions**. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz: Unfortunately my normal reference source for this (wikipedia :) doesn't give enough details. But logically, an equijoin with "AND"s can be seen as an equijoin with a single equality comparison on a multi-column key (which is how you model it in LINQ). A join with "OR"s *can't* be seen that way.